# Python using .csv files in terminal

Tags: python, terminal

I wrote the following script that runs perfectly when using pyCharm, but when I go to run it in a terminal it gives me these errors:

```
  File "/Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/firstfile/trial.py", line 6, in <module>
    r = pf.read_csv('python.csv')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 562, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 315, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 645, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 799, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1213, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 358, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:3427)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 628, in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas/parser.c:6861)
IOError: File python.csv does not exist
```

Could someone point in the the right direction? I am guessing that it has to do with the csv file not being in the right path or directory. Right now I have the csv file saved in the same folder as my .py project. I also checked and made sure I have the right packages installed, so I do not think it is that.

```
import csv
import pandas as pf

r = pf.read_csv('python.csv')
r.head()

print r.describe()
tradeDates = r['Trade Date'].unique()

r.name = 'Trade Date'
for trades in tradeDates:
outfilename = trades
printName = outfilename + ".csv"
print printName
r[r['Trade Date'] == trades].to_csv(printName, index=False)
```

Comment: .csv file path:    /Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/firstfile/python.csv ||||| .py file path:   /Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/firstfile/trial.py

Comment: How do you run the code in therminal?

Comment: python /Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/firstfile/trial.py

Comment: Try putting the full file path in your program

Comment: Try changing your directory to /Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/firstfile and running python trial.py

Comment: i put the file path in my program and tried rerunning it the same way and got this: -bash: /Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/firstfile/trial.py: Permission denied

Comment: got it to work by changing path and then running python trial.py

Comment: thank you very much both of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run *python /Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/firstfile/trial.py* python looks for csv file in your current directory, not in */Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/firstfile*.
You either need to change your directory before running the code, or you need to use the full path in **trial.py** like this:

```
import csv
import pandas as pf

r = pf.read_csv('/Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/firstfile/python.csv')
r.head()
```